# pyTelegramBotAPI is there another way for adding the markup width to a list of buttons?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

the title is pretty much what I need, but Ill explain why I need it.
I am using a for loop, then inside, I have a loop that adds the buttons to an array, the problem is that I must make a separated button at the bottom, that doesn't have loop, therefore, I searched and found a way to do it:

```
buttons = []
def gen_markup():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 1
    for x, y in zip(name, conexion):
        buttons.append(InlineKeyboardButton(x, url=y))
    buttons.append(InlineKeyboardButton("Añadir Botón", callback_data="add_btn"))
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([buttons])
    return reply_markup
```

So, it's all working, except that the width of the markup does not, and I understand it, because I am returning the **reply_markup** variable, instead of the **markup** one.
So basically I need a fixment to this, if you find another way of course I am open to it, I just putted that one in the title because it is the only one I can think about.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, the rest depends on your python skills

```
def gen_markup():
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    markup.add(*[InlineKeyboardButton(x, url=y)) for x, y in zip(name, conexion)])
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("Añadir Botón", callback_data="add_btn"))
    
    return reply_markup
```